# Load function returning array or string from DLL created in Delphi

Tags: interoperability, .netlink

I'm trying to call a function from a 32-bit DLL created in Delphi. My (simplified) function is defined in Delphi like so:

```
library my;

type TArrayOfReal = array of Real;

function sumarrayreal(x,y : Real) : TArrayOfReal;
begin
  SetLength(Result,3);
  Result[0]:=x;
  Result[1]:=y;
  Result[2]:=x+y;
end;

exports sumarrayreal;
```

I'm using a special type TArrayOfReal here because Delphi functions (as far as I know) can't return arrays, not even static ones.

Then I call my DLL from a 64-bit version of Mathematica 11:

```
(*In*)
Needs["NETLink`"]

UninstallNET[]
InstallNET["Force32Bit" -> True]

fun1 = DefineDLLFunction["sumarrayreal", 
  "my.dll", 
  "double[]", {"double", "double"}]

(*Out*)
Function[Null, 
 If[NETLink`DLL`Private`checkArgCount["sumarrayreal", {##1}, 2], 
  Wolfram`NETLink`DynamicDLLNamespace`DLLWrapper2`sumarrayreal[##1], 
$Failed], {HoldAll}]
```

When I try to use this function

```
(*In*)
fun1[2., 3.]

(*Out*)
$Failed
```

I receive an error:

> A .NET exception occurred:
>   "System.Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalDirectiveException: Cannot
>   marshal 'return value': Invalid managed/unmanaged type combination.

Even a function that returns a string

```
(*delphi code*)
function sumarray(x,y : Real) : string;
begin
  Result := FloatToStr(x)+' '+FloatToStr(y) + ' '+ FloatToStr(x+y)
end;

(*Mathematica In*)
fun2 = DefineDLLFunction["sumarray", 
  "my.dll", 
  "string", {"double", "double"}]
```

doesn't work:

> A .NET exception occurred: "System.AccessViolationException: Attempted
>   to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that
>   other memory is corrupt.

But a function that returns a single value DOES work:

```
(*delphi code*)
function sum(x,y : Real) : Real;
begin
  Result := x+y;
end;

(*In*)
fun3 = DefineDLLFunction["sum", 
  "my.dll", 
  "double", {"double", "double"}]   

 (*Out*)
Function[Null, 
 If[NETLink`DLL`Private`checkArgCount["sum", {##1}, 2], 
  Wolfram`NETLink`DynamicDLLNamespace`DLLWrapper1`sum[##1], $Failed], 
{HoldAll}]

(*In*)
fun3[2., 3.]

(*Out*)
5.
```

The problem is that I absolutely need to return an array (or a string at worst), not a single value! What do I do with that? Thank you.

Comment: Find out what calling convention Delphi uses and set the CallingConvention option of DefineDLLFunction appropriately.

Comment: @Szabolcs AFAIK Deplhi uses "StdCall". I tried this as CallingConvention option, and "CDecl", and "ThisCall", and Automatic. Still doesn't work.

Comment: Perhaps you will have better luck if you ask on StackOverflow about how to call a Delphi DLL from C# (leave the Mathematica part out).  Unfortunately I am not very familiar with this technology.

Comment: is this question supposed to be in stckoverflow instead?